# Keras: Multiple Inputs for fit_generator using flow_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is it possible to have two flow_from_directory in a fit_generator?

For example

```
train_generator_1 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir_1,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

train_generator_2 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir_2,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

custom_vgg_model.fit_generator(
    [train_generator_1, train_generator_2],
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples,
    callbacks=[checkpointer, csv_logger])
```

Comment: Do you want two parallel inputs? Does your model use two inputs? And how about the outputs? Two parallel outputs?

Comment: @DanielMöller Yes, My model has two CNN. Each with different inputs. The output is the same. The inputs are basically the same image but each CNN has a different pre-processed image.

Comment: Ok, and the outputs... Do you want to take them from generator 1 or from generator 2?

Comment: @DanielMöller The outputs should be the same for both generators. So either is fine.

Comment: I appreciate your kind help! Another [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404993/keras-how-to-use-fit-generator-with-multiple-inputs/55719999#55719999) I recommend you.

Answer (score 4):

You can try making a generator that contains both:

In python 3:

```
def doubleGenerator(generator1,generator2):

    while True:
        for (x1,y1),(x2,y2) in zip(generator1,generator2):
            yield ([x1,x2],y1)
```

Comment: A question: is this checking the names of the files found in each directory? How is it able to connect say, imageA1 with label A and imageA2, which also has label A?