# How to use fit_generator with multiple inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, generator

Is it possible to have two fit_generator?

I'm creating a model with two inputs,
The model configuration is shown below.

[image]

Label Y uses the same labeling for X1 and X2 data.

The following error will continue to occur.

> *Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected
>   to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:
>   [array([[[[0.75686276, 0.75686276, 0.75686276],
>            [0.75686276, 0.75686276, 0.75686276],
>            [0.75686276, 0.75686276, 0.75686276],
>            ...,
>            [0.65882355, 0.65882355, 0.65882355...*

My code looks like this:

```python
def generator_two_img(X1, X2, Y,batch_size):
    generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=15,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')

    genX1 = generator.flow(X1, Y, batch_size=batch_size)
    genX2 = generator.flow(X2, Y, batch_size=batch_size)

    while True:
        X1 = genX1.__next__()
        X2 = genX2.__next__()
        yield [X1, X2], Y
  """
      .................................
  """
hist = model.fit_generator(generator_two_img(x_train, x_train_landmark, 
                y_train, batch_size),
                steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch,
                callbacks = callbacks,
                validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation),
                validation_steps=x_validation.shape[0] // batch_size, 
                `enter code here`verbose=1)
```

Comment: Does your dataset contain many classes?? Because I tried the sloution and it does not work, because I have different classes and I want to create a model that takes two images that from the same class. And I do not know how to do this :/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this generator:

```python
def generator_two_img(X1, X2, y, batch_size):
    genX1 = gen.flow(X1, y,  batch_size=batch_size, seed=1)
    genX2 = gen.flow(X2, y, batch_size=batch_size, seed=1)
    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X1i[1]
```

Generator for 3 inputs:

```python
def generator_three_img(X1, X2, X3, y, batch_size):
    genX1 = gen.flow(X1, y,  batch_size=batch_size, seed=1)
    genX2 = gen.flow(X2, y, batch_size=batch_size, seed=1)
    genX3 = gen.flow(X3, y, batch_size=batch_size, seed=1)
    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()
        X3i = genX3.next()
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[0], X3i[0]], X1i[1]
```

**EDIT** (add generator, output image and numpy array, and target)

```python
#X1 is an image, y is the target, X2 is a numpy array - other data input        
def gen_flow_for_two_inputs(X1, X2, y):
    genX1 = gen.flow(X1,y,  batch_size=batch_size,seed=666)
    genX2 = gen.flow(X1,X2, batch_size=batch_size,seed=666)
    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()
        #Assert arrasy are equal - this was for peace of mind, but slows down training
        #np.testing.assert_array_equal(X1i[0],X2i[0])
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[1]], X1i[1]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the syntax of the last step `yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X1i[1]`. For instance, how can I do it for 3 inputs?

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen just made a generator for 3 inputs

Comment: By the way, it should be **list**, while **CANNOT be tuple** (I fell into this pitfall...) You can see it by source code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_generator.py

Comment: Why is only `X1i[1]` being returned by the generator but not `X2i[1]` and `Xi2[1]`?

Comment: X1[1] are the labels, as labels in both X1 and X2 are same, so you can return any one of them

Comment: @TalhaAnwar salam, I need to get `fpr` and `tpr` using `fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(true_val_labels, preds)`. How do I get `true_val_labels` in this case? For more info please refer to this [link](https://gist.github.com/RyanAkilos/3808c17f79e77c4117de35aa68447045#gistcomment-3439342)

Comment: @IoannisNasios what if the first input is an image and the second input is 1d feature like 0 or 1. how should I modify this function

Comment: @TunaYüce I have added a generator for 2 inputs, one image and one any other array.

Answer (score 10):

I have an implementation for multiple inputs for `TimeseriesGenerator` that I have adapted it (I have not been able to test it unfortunately) to meet this example with `ImageDataGenerator`. My approach was to build a wrapper class for the multiple generators from `keras.utils.Sequence` and then implement the base methods of it: `__len__` and `__getitem__`:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils import Sequence


class MultipleInputGenerator(Sequence):
    """Wrapper of 2 ImageDataGenerator"""

    def __init__(self, X1, X2, Y, batch_size):
        # Keras generator
        self.generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=15, 
                                            width_shift_range=0.2,
                                            height_shift_range=0.2,
                                            shear_range=0.2,
                                            zoom_range=0.2,
                                            horizontal_flip=True, 
                                            fill_mode='nearest')

        # Real time multiple input data augmentation
        self.genX1 = self.generator.flow(X1, Y, batch_size=batch_size)
        self.genX2 = self.generator.flow(X2, Y, batch_size=batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        """It is mandatory to implement it on Keras Sequence"""
        return self.genX1.__len__()

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Getting items from the 2 generators and packing them"""
        X1_batch, Y_batch = self.genX1.__getitem__(index)
        X2_batch, Y_batch = self.genX2.__getitem__(index)

        X_batch = [X1_batch, X2_batch]

        return X_batch, Y_batch
```

You can use this generator with `model.fit_generator()` once the generator has been instanced.

Comment: Hey, do you have the original code for TimeseriesGenerator somewhere?

Comment: No man, sorry, it's been a long time ago... :( I only back up latest projects

Comment: @JVGD I'm a couple of months late to this post but, would you know how to make this generator work with more than 1 worker? I based my generator on your post (with modifications) but whenever I give a value to workers in `model.fit()` it throws some unknown errors. Thank you in advance !!

Comment: @Wazaki, not a couple of months but a couple of years, it has been almost 1 and a half year since I changed to pytorch, so I am off the grid with this right now. Sorry for not being able to help you :(( but if you can use pytorch seriously, we gained so much we we moved

Comment: @JVGD Oh sorry, I meant to say "years" but wrote "months" instead. Thanks !! I'll see if I can switch to Pytorch.