# What is the proper way to design a data generator for a multi-input Keras model?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to design a multi-input keras model.  We are working with images (128x128x3) of mathematical knots.  I have set up a model that takes three inputs.  The three inputs will be

1). Non-rotated picture of a knot

2). Same knot as 1 but rotated about it's y axis 90 degrees

3). Same knot as 1 but rotated about it's x axis 90 degrees

The model is good and will compile properly.  The problem I am having is that I am using fit_generator to train my model, and I cannot seem to get my data generator to work properly.  Here is my code for my data generator:

```
def DataGen(in1,in2,in3,in1_label,in2_label,in3_label, batch_size):

    in1 = np.array(in1)
    in1 = np.reshape(in1, (in1.shape[0],128,128,3))

    in2 = np.array(in2)
    in2 = np.reshape(in2, (in2.shape[0],128,128,3))

    in3 = np.array(in3)
    in3 = np.reshape(in3, (in3.shape[0],128,128,3))

    L = len(in1)

    batch_start = 0
    batch_end = batch_size


    gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

    genX1 = gen.flow(in1, in1_label,  batch_size=batch_size, seed=1)
    genX2 = gen.flow(in2, in2_label, batch_size=batch_size, seed=1)
    genX3 = gen.flow(in3, in3_label, batch_size=batch_size, seed=1)
    #this line is just to make the generator infinite, keras needs that    
    while True:

        limit = min(batch_end, L)
        #in1
        X1i = genX1.next()
        print(X1i[0].shape)
        #in2
        X2i = genX2.next()
        #in3
        X3i = genX3.next()
        #print(Y.shape)
        #print(Y1.shape)
        #print(Y2.shape)
        label = np.concatenate([X1i[1],X2i[1],X3i[1]])
        #print(label.shape)
        #print(X1i[1].shape)
        yield [X1i[0],X2i[0],X3i[0]],np.array(label) #a tuple with two numpy arrays with batch_size samples     

        batch_start += batch_size   
        batch_end += batch_size

        if batch_start > L - batch_size:
            batch_start = 0
            batch_end = batch_size
```

If I run the neural network with this code it generates the following error messaage:

```
Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 30 input samples and 90 target samples.
```

Which makes me think I should not concatenate the label, and just return a list of labels, along with the list of batches...If i yield the following

```
yield [X1i[0],X2i[0],X3i[0]],[X1i[1],X2i[1],X3i[1]]
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 3 arrays: [array([[0., 1., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 1.],
   [1., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0.],
   [0....
```

So I do not know what to do to fix it.  The model has 45,000 input images, 15,000 go to each of the three inputs.  The model will also have 45,000 validation images, again with 15,000 going to each input.

Every input(set of 15,000 images) has a corresponding label with the following structure: First 5,000 elements of the list= label 0, Second 5,000 elements of the list=label 1, Third 5,000 elements of the list=label 2.  The labels are all One hot encoded as well.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

My data generator is based off of:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405175/5432071

My Jupyter notebook code can be viewed here:
https://uofstthomasmn-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/ward0001_stthomas_edu/EcHhuXpXl1VJu8yKZaWRdKkBdwVrD6AEs3hd4Kuwk2Cl3g?e=tlQTGx

For the Jupyer notebook link, you will have to click the link, then click download...as the html file will not be displayed on onedrive.

To summarize my question: What is wrong with my data generator for multi-input models?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exactly the output of your model? Do you have a single output? My first guess would be that you are concatenating along the wrong axis. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: @sdcbr The main neural network's last layer is just a relu output, so I want the three inputs each to pass an image through the neural network, the three relu outputs to be concatenated into a single tensor, then that tensor is passed into a softmax classification layer. The softmax classification layer only classifies three classes.  Each input is 15,000 images: 5,000 of each of the three classes. Here is a model picture : https://uofstthomasmn-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/ward0001_stthomas_edu/ESiVHZycQGtEvi4nJ7MXPgQBjombRpS56qeRLd1GEtKduw?e=soNa8B   Tell my if this helps you understand?

Comment: I understand your architecture, but I don't understand why you are concatenating and yielding multiple labels. You appear to have only one label per tuple of three images, right? So your generator should yield something like [X1, X2, X3], Y, where Y is of shape (batch_size, 1). No?

Comment: @sdcbr It may be because I am confused as to how ImageDataGenerator works.  So in my case, in1,in2,in3 all have the same label. So if I call genX1 = gen.flow(in1,in1_label,32), and genX2 = gen.flow(in2, in2_label,32) and then call genX1.next(), and genX2.next()...will genX1.next() and genX2.next() have the exact same label? Or are the batches shuffled? Do you understand the question? Thanks btw!!