# Keras: Create a custom generator for two input model using flow_from _directory() function

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, generator, conv-neural-network

I was trying to train my siamese network with `fit_generator()`,I learned from this answer: [Keras: How to use fit_generator with multiple inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404993/keras-how-to-use-fit-generator-with-multiple-inputs) that the best way to do this was to create your own generator that yield the multiple data points, my problem was that I retrieve my data with `flow_from_directory()` function and I didn't know if that was possible.

This is my attempt to readapt a generator for my problem:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np

model = load_model("siamese_model.h5")

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

def generator():
    t1 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,target_size = (150, 150), batch_size = 20, class_mode = 'categorical',shuffle = True)
    t2 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,target_size = (150, 150), batch_size = 20, class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle = True)
    while True:
        d1,y = t1.next()
        d2 = t2.next()
        yield ([d1[0], d2[0]],y)

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',optimizer= optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit_generator(generator(),
                              steps_per_epoch = 10,
                              epochs = 5)
```

My code give me the exact same error as when I tried to fit my model without the custom generator:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[0.14509805, 0.15686275, 0.16862746],
         [0.14509805, 0.15686275, 0.16862746],
         [0.14509805, 0.15686275, 0.16862746],
         ...,
         [0.14117648, 0.15294118, 0.16862746...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
while True:
    d1 = t1.next()
    d2 = t2.next()
    yield ([d1[0], d2[0]], d1[1])
```

Also , your input will be shuffle in a different way so they will lose their link if you put them in a certain order in your folder.

I would suggest :

```
t1 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,target_size = (150, 150), batch_size = 20, class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle = False, seed='13')

t2 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,target_size = (150, 150), batch_size = 20, class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle = False, seed='13')
```

or with the same seed for shuffle

```
t1 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,target_size = (150, 150), batch_size = 20, class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle = True, seed='13')

t2 = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(base_dir,target_size = (150, 150), batch_size = 20, class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle = True, seed='13')
```

Comment: I followed the same. I am getting below error. 
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [20,3] vs. [20,4096]
  [[node gradient_tape/categorical_crossentropy/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at <ipython-input-46-6c7cbd8f3fb5>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4028]

Function call stack:
train_function