# Siamese Networks in Keras - Errors

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, siamese-network

I have trained a siamese net on a image data set and got some errors which are given below.

```py
a = Input(shape=(256,256,3))
b = Input(shape=(256,256,3))
#create model
model = Sequential()
#add model layers
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=10, activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3),strides=(1,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=7, activation='relu',strides=(1,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, activation='relu',strides=(1,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=4, activation='relu',strides=(1,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(7, activation='sigmoid'))
encoded_l = model(a)
encoded_r = model(b)
L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]))
L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])
prediction = Dense(4096,activation='sigmoid')(L1_distance)

# Connect the inputs with the outputs
model = Model(inputs=[a,b],outputs=prediction)
# plot graph
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

I have trained model on image dataset:

```py
train_data_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/jaffe augmented/train'
validation_data_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/jaffe augmented/validation'
test_data_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/jaffe augmented/test'
img_rows = 256
img_cols = 256
epochs = 2
batch_size = 32
num_of_train_samples = 1026
num_of_validation_samples =126
num_of_test_samples =21
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_path,
                                                target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
                                                batch_size=batch_size)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_path,
                                                    target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_data_path,
                                                target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
                                                batch_size=batch_size)                                             
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
history=model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch=num_of_train_samples // batch_size,
                epochs=epochs,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                validation_steps=num_of_validation_samples//batch_size)
```

I have got the following error.

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your 
>       model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following 
>       list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[1.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
>            [1.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
>            [1.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
>            ...,
>            [1.        , 1.        , 1.        ...

Comment: please someone help its urgent .please

Answer (score 0):

`ImageDataGenerator` by default will give only one image at a time.
But your model requires 2 images as input (`model = Model(inputs=[a,b],outputs=prediction)`)

You can refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930476/keras-create-a-custom-generator-for-two-input-model-using-flow-from-directory) to build a custom data generator to yield 2 images

Answer (score 0):

If your both inputs are fed from same dataset. You can use below code.

```
history=model.fit_generator([train_generator,train_generator], 
                steps_per_epoch=num_of_train_samples // batch_size,
                epochs=epochs,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                validation_steps=num_of_validation_samples//batch_size)
```