# Understanding 'follow_links' argument in Keras's ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: image, keras, generator

The Keras documentations says

> 'follow_links: Whether to follow symlinks inside class subdirectories
>   (default: False)'

, but what is the exact role of this argument?

Comment: Can you explain, what exactly is unclear?

Comment: What is symlinks? And what is symlinks inside a class subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlinks are used to link a file or directory. For example you have a symlink, which points to the latest version of any installed version of python.exe (or any other file or directory), while you have multiple version installed.

Following this symlink meens you don´t see the symlink as a symlink, but resolve the target file/directory, where it points to. In the python example you would open the latest python console. In the keras example keras would also consider symlinks as image input data. A long you don´t have symlinks in your data directory, you can just let it be False.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link