# tensorflow use image path as training input

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory

Is there any way to use a list containing the relative path to all the training image files as an input when running model.fit?

For example if the array is like:

```
['images/00001.png', 'images/00002.png', ... 'images/9999.png']
```

How can I use this as the input to train my model?
All the images are grayscale and I don't want to convert the image into an array as that results in a memory error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing your images in a tuple. It works well with Tensorflow, and can hold lots of data when needed.

```
thistuple = ("images/00001.png", "images/00002.png", "images/9999.png")
print(thistuple)
```

**EDIT**

Create a ImageDataGenerator in Keras

```
#create a data generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
```

Then use that generator to load in the images

```
#load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train/', class_mode='binary', 
batch_size=64)
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try it out.
Would i be able to use this directly as the x train data or do I have to open the images first.

Comment: You would just have to load in all images in a folder, preferably with a loop, then just add them to a tuple. I assume since you are working with images that you have already located areas that you want to be found in images and stored them to be used later?

Comment: Yeah all the images are in the images folder. So I assume with this, i can just do model.fit(x=thistuple, **args) and if the images exist in the specified path, it'll work?

Comment: Kares has this class called ImageDataGenerator, wich you could great a data generated with this code `datagen = ImageDataGenerator()`. Then just load in the images like so `#load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)`

Comment: I'm sure that there is a way to do this, but I personally dont know how to do it. This stack form might have some answers to what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355524/use-multiple-directories-for-flow-from-directory-in-keras

Comment: Thanks. After some looking around using your suggestion, I was able to find flow_from_dataframe which was exactly what I needed.