# keras `ImageDataGenerator`: apply different augmentation in different directories

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-generation

I have multiple data directories with the same subdirectory structure. As below—

```
.
└── data/
    ├── directory1/
    │   ├── train/
    │   │   ├── class1
    │   │   └── class2
    │   ├── validation/
    │   │   ├── class1
    │   │   └── class2
    │   └── test
    └── directory2/
        ├── train/
        │   ├── class1
        │   └── class2
        ├── validation/
        │   ├── class1
        │   └── class2
        └── test
```

But the attributes of the images in the second directory are different from the first. Such as the image size of the second directory, or the color mode is different from the other. Also, I will do image augmentation in one directory, but not in another.  I mean, I want to process the images of the two directories separately but feed them in the model in a consistent form.

That means the structure of the directories are the same, but the image attributes and augmentation will be different. How Keras `ImageDataGenerator` can be used in such a situation? Specifically, I want to use the `flow_from_directory` method.

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51355524/7829174), but it did not solve my problem, because this question is about applying the same attribute and augmentation to different directories, which is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had fallen into this problem several days ago. After doing a lot of research on the net, I can come up with an idea even though I could not find a suitable solution directly. Follow symlink will not work here because the image attributes in the two directories are entirely different; again, different image augmentation will be applied.

Here we have to create two separate image generators and configure them separately. Then we have to merge them. I find this idea, which solved my problem, [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9969#issuecomment-420371428).

But we need to tweak a little. Since the two directories have different numbers of images, simply combining two data generators of the same size will create an unbalanced share of images that are ready to feed. Relatively more images will be feed to the model from the directory that has fewer images. So the batch size of these two data generators has to be calculated based on the number of images in the respective directory. And that is the originality of my solution here.

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils import Sequence
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os


class MergedGenerators(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, batch_size, generators=[], sub_batch_size=[]):
        self.generators = generators
        self.sub_batch_size = sub_batch_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(
            sum([(len(self.generators[idx]) * self.sub_batch_size[idx])
                 for idx in range(len(self.sub_batch_size))]) /
            self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Getting items from the generators and packing them"""

        X_batch = []
        Y_batch = []
        for generator in self.generators:
            if generator.class_mode is None:
                x1 = generator[index % len(generator)]
                X_batch = [*X_batch, *x1]

            else:
                x1, y1 = generator[index % len(generator)]
                X_batch = [*X_batch, *x1]
                Y_batch = [*Y_batch, *y1]

        if self.generators[0].class_mode is None:
            return np.array(X_batch)
        return np.array(X_batch), np.array(Y_batch)


def build_datagenerator(dir1=None, dir2=None, batch_size=32):
    n_images_in_dir1 = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(dir1)])
    n_images_in_dir2 = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(dir2)])

    # Have to set different batch size for two generators as number of images
    # in those two directories are not same. As we have to equalize the image
    # share in the generators
    generator1_batch_size = int((n_images_in_dir1 * batch_size) /
                                (n_images_in_dir1 + n_images_in_dir2))

    generator2_batch_size = batch_size - generator1_batch_size

    generator1 = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1. / 255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        rotation_range=5.,
        horizontal_flip=True,
    )

    generator2 = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1. / 255,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=False,
    )

    # generator2 has different image augmentation attributes than generaor1
    generator1 = generator1.flow_from_directory(
        dir1,
        target_size=(128, 128),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode=None,
        batch_size=generator1_batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=42,
        interpolation="bicubic",
    )

    generator2 = generator2.flow_from_directory(
        dir2,
        target_size=(128, 128),
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode=None,
        batch_size=generator2_batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=42,
        interpolation="bicubic",
    )

    return MergedGenerators(
        batch_size,
        generators=[generator1, generator2],
        sub_batch_size=[generator1_batch_size, generator2_batch_size])


def test_datagen(batch_size=32):
    datagen = build_datagenerator(dir1="./asdf",
                                  dir2="./asdf2",
                                  batch_size=batch_size)

    print("Datagenerator length (Batch count):", len(datagen))

    for batch_count, image_batch in enumerate(datagen):
        if batch_count == 1:
            break

        print("Images: ", image_batch.shape)

        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
        for i in range(image_batch.shape[0]):
            plt.subplot(1, batch_size, i + 1)
            plt.imshow(image_batch[i], interpolation='nearest')
            plt.axis('off')
            plt.tight_layout()


test_datagen(4)
```

To get the batch size of sub-generators:

[image: b = \frac{B \times n}{\sum{n}}]

```
Where,
b = Batch Size Of Any Sub-generator
B = Desired Batch Size Of The Merged Generator
n = Number Of Images In That Directory Of Sub-generator
the sum of n = Total Number Of Images In All Directories
```